# Failures when running "mvn test"

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

What can be the reason that I can successfully run testNG suite (14 tests) directly from selenium eclipse but when I am trying to run it throw CMD with command : mvn test
It's stops after 6 tests every time ?
Also The 1st test success from selenium and here is always failed.
BTW : When I am trying to do : mvn clean or compile its success.

```
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   OrderBE.order:75->addItems:113 » IndexOutOfBounds Index: 22, Size: 22
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:20 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-01T17:06:15+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project miron: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Program Files\Selenium\Projects\BE UAT\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: The test is failing... you have to fix the test....

Answer (score 0):

are you running them in parallel?

it could be the limit of the number of browers per processor (I had an issue like that)

Try restarting the driver if grid, and changing the limit

Comment: No, I am not run them parallel

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your TestNG tests in src\main\test folder and not in main\java